# Cannot access websites on apache from outside the server

Tags: linux, apache, debian

I have a debian 7.5 based Ubuntu server, apache 2.2.22.
It's a rather vanilla installed XAMP used as a basic web server.
It used to work fine and I have no idea why it stopped working suddenly (there was some maintenance today but it worked when I left it - I changed partition sizes with Gparted).

When I try to access a website from the server (tried with w3m) all is working OK, including PHP and MySQL access.

When I try to access the same host (using a domain) from the outside, the browser keeps loading for a long while, eventually (after few minutes) saying the page could not be loaded.

I made sure that ports are open and accessible with outside scanner.

So I'm sure the Apache is available (working from inside the network, websites loading from SSH using w3M and pinging)
I'm sure the server is connected to the web (I can use putty to SSH)
the host is resolving to the correct IP (but won't ping from outside, only inside)
The ports seems to be opened (scanned and got OK for port 80)

I'm not a professional IT, so If there is info I can add that could help just ask away.
would really appreciate any idea or direction.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I still suspect the UFW/iptables firewall is blocking all incoming connections...  Please go through this article and double check

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-server-disable-firewall/

If you're sure that the firewall config is OK, please try packet capturing with Wireshark to see what's going on underneath.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOTCRqa8U9Y How to install

Comment: Thanks for taking the offering your experience - After 12 hours of not working, it just started working again :\

Comment: Great article, just finished reading it. Seems i'll try your advice with wireshark and update back here.
Have a great weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help,
Oddly enough - It just started working again after 12 hours of not working.
A friend of mine, an IT person just called to try and help, and he simply connected (5 mins after I tried) and said it's all working for him.
I tried, and it's working for me also.
Have no idea why it stopped working, and why it is working now.
I think it might be an ISP problem or a router issue... The server is in our offices so I guess it could be both. I just don't understand why SSH would work and HTTP wouldn't.